# how can I solve the parrot talking problem?

Tags: python

I am using `codingbat` for practice and I can't solve this problem:

> We have a loud talking parrot. The "hour" parameter is the current
> hour time in the range 0..23. We are in trouble if the parrot is
> talking and the hour is before 7 or after 20. Return True if we are in
> trouble.

Here is my code:

```
def parrot_trouble(talking, hour):
  if talking == True and hour != range(7,21) :
    return(True)
  else:
    return(False)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You wanted `not in` instead of `!=`

Comment: `return talking and hour in range(7, 21)`.

Answer (score 3):

`hour != range(7,21) :` should be `hour not in range(7,21) :`

Comment: `hour not in range(7,21)` feels more idiomatic.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

```
hour != range(7,21)
```

Perhaps what you meant is:

```
not hour in range(7,21)
```

Or equivalently (and perhaps more idiomatically):

```
hour not in range(7,21)
```

`!=` performs an **equality** check.

`hour` can *never* be **equal** to `range(7,21)`, because `hour` is [an `int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int), and `range(..)` is... [a `range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)!